# Trying to change the order of filtered galleries in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, filter

I am working with a wordpress site that displays galleries on a portfolio page. The problem I am having is there are no options to display the galleries in a custom order, it just displays the galleries alphabetically. I have tried changing the slugs of the gallery names so that they are chronological, matching the order I would like them to appear, but this does not work. Below is the code, what would I need to change to make it display them in order of the slug names?

```
<div class="filter row animated">
    <div class="albums">
        <div class="content">
            <?php if ( $albums && !is_wp_error( $albums ) ) : ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php if ( $portfolio_showall == "on") : ?>
                        <li data-album='all' class='all selected'><span><?php echo __( 'All', 'turin'); ?></span></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $albums as $album ) { ?>
                                <li data-album="<?php echo esc_attr( $album->slug ); ?>"><span><?php echo esc_attr( $album->name ); ?></span></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                <select>
                    <?php if ( $portfolio_showall == "on") : ?>
                        <option data-album='all'>
                            <?php echo __( 'All', 'turin'); ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $albums as $album ) { ?>
                                <option data-album="<?php echo esc_attr( $album->slug ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_attr( $album->name ); ?>
                                </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What data contain array $albums ?

Comment: you should add this code 
<pre><?php print_r($albums);?></pre>. 
Before <div class="filter row animated">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just solved it, there was another bit of code that needed changing, I changed

```
        $album_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'album' );
    if( !empty($album_terms) ) {
        foreach ( $album_terms as $album_term  ) {
            $term_IDs[] = $album_term->term_id;
        }
        $album_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'include' => $term_IDs, 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'all' );
    } else {
        $album_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'all' );
    }
    $albums = get_terms( 'album', $album_args );
    ?>
```

to read

```
        $album_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'album' );
    if( !empty($album_terms) ) {
        foreach ( $album_terms as $album_term  ) {
            $term_IDs[] = $album_term->term_id;
        }
        $album_args = array( 'orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC', 'include' => $term_IDs, 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'all' );
    } else {
        $album_args = array( 'orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'all' );
    }
    $albums = get_terms( 'album', $album_args );
    ?>
```

and it all seems to work now!